# JTabbedPane imbedded in JTabbedPane pushing bounds with too many tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am trying to code a checklist style program and am using a JTabbedPane inside another JTabbedPane. Everything was fine until I tried adding another set of tabs under one tab. Then the bounds of the overall JTabbedPane started increasing and going off screen. Below is the pane before the extra tab. [image: 1]

And below here is the pane after the extra tab. [image: 2]

I'm wondering if there is possibly a limit of some sort to how many tabs I can do. Only thing is I have other top tabs with way more right tabs so that doesn't make too much sense.

Here is the code for setting up the components and tabs

```
private void init() {
        e4cPanel = new JPanel();
        e4cPanel.setBackground(back);

        gceaScroll = new JScrollPane();
        gceaScroll.setBackground(back);
        gceaScroll.setBorder(null);
        gceaScroll.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        gceaScroll.setVerticalScrollBar(new JCustomScrollBar());
        gceaScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(25);
        gceaPanel = new JPanel();
        gceaPanel.setBackground(back);
        gceaScroll.setViewportView(gceaPanel);

        formScroll = new JScrollPane();
        formScroll.setBackground(back);
        formScroll.setBorder(null);
        formScroll.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        formScroll.setVerticalScrollBar(new JCustomScrollBar());
        formScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(25);
        formPanel = new JPanel();
        formPanel.setBackground(back);
        formScroll.setViewportView(formPanel);

        legScroll = new JScrollPane();
        legScroll.setBackground(back);
        legScroll.setBorder(null);
        legScroll.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        legScroll.setVerticalScrollBar(new JCustomScrollBar());
        legScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(25);
        legPanel = new JPanel();
        legPanel.setBackground(back);
        legScroll.setViewportView(legPanel);

        mytScroll = new JScrollPane();
        mytScroll.setBackground(back);
        mytScroll.setBorder(null);
        mytScroll.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        mytScroll.setVerticalScrollBar(new JCustomScrollBar());
        mytScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(25);
        mytPanel = new JPanel();
        mytPanel.setBackground(back);
        mytScroll.setViewportView(mytPanel);

        giftScroll = new JScrollPane();
        giftScroll.setBackground(back);
        giftScroll.setBorder(null);
        giftScroll.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        giftScroll.setVerticalScrollBar(new JCustomScrollBar());
        giftScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(25);
        giftPanel = new JPanel();
        giftPanel.setBackground(back);
        giftScroll.setViewportView(giftPanel);

        colScroll = new JScrollPane();
        colScroll.setBackground(back);
        colScroll.setBorder(null);
        colScroll.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        colScroll.setVerticalScrollBar(new JCustomScrollBar());
        colScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(25);
        colPanel = new JPanel();
        colPanel.setBackground(back);
        colScroll.setViewportView(colPanel);

        upgScroll = new JScrollPane();
        upgScroll.setBackground(back);
        upgScroll.setBorder(null);
        upgScroll.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        upgScroll.setVerticalScrollBar(new JCustomScrollBar());
        upgScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(25);
        upgPanel = new JPanel();
        upgPanel.setBackground(back);
        upgScroll.setViewportView(upgPanel);

        batScroll = new JScrollPane();
        batScroll.setBackground(back);
        batScroll.setBorder(null);
        batScroll.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        batScroll.setVerticalScrollBar(new JCustomScrollBar());
        batScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(25);
        batPanel = new JPanel();
        batPanel.setBackground(back);
        batScroll.setViewportView(batPanel);

        tmScroll = new JScrollPane();
        tmScroll.setBackground(back);
        tmScroll.setBorder(null);
        tmScroll.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        tmScroll.setVerticalScrollBar(new JCustomScrollBar());
        tmScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(25);
        tmPanel = new JPanel();
        tmPanel.setBackground(back);
        tmScroll.setViewportView(tmPanel);

        hmPanel = new JPanel();
        hmPanel.setBackground(back);

        berryScroll = new JScrollPane();
        berryScroll.setBackground(back);
        berryScroll.setBorder(null);
        berryScroll.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        berryScroll.setVerticalScrollBar(new JCustomScrollBar());
        berryScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(25);
        berryPanel = new JPanel();
        berryPanel.setBackground(back);
        berryScroll.setViewportView(berryPanel);

        setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.RIGHT);
        addTab("Elite 4/Champion", e4cPanel);
        addTab("Gotta Catch 'Em All", gceaScroll);
        addTab("Forms", formScroll);
        addTab("Legendaries", legScroll);
        addTab("Mythicals", mytScroll);
        addTab("Mystery Gifts", giftScroll);
        addTab("Collectables", colScroll);
        addTab("Upgrades", upgScroll);
        addTab("Battle", batScroll);
//      addTab("TM's", tmScroll);
//      addTab("HM's", hmPanel);
//      addTab("Berries", berryScroll);
}
```

As you can see, I'm also using a custom UI tabbed pane so here is the code for that incase it might be in there.

```
package customs.tabs;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTabbedPaneUI;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.Animator;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.TimingTarget;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.interpolation.PropertySetter;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MaterialTabbed extends JTabbedPane {
    private final int orientation;

    public MaterialTabbed(int orientation) {
        this.orientation = orientation;
        MaterialTabbedUI ui = new MaterialTabbedUI();
        setTabPlacement(orientation);
        setUI(ui);
    }

    public class MaterialTabbedUI extends MetalTabbedPaneUI {
        private Animator animator;
        private Rectangle currentRectangle;
        private TimingTarget target;

        public void setCurrentRectangle(Rectangle currentRectangle) {
            this.currentRectangle = currentRectangle;
            repaint();
        }

        public MaterialTabbedUI() {
        }

        @Override
        public void installUI(JComponent jc) {
            super.installUI(jc);
            animator = new Animator(500);
            animator.setResolution(0);
            animator.setAcceleration(.5f);
            animator.setDeceleration(.5f);
            tabPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
                    int selected = tabPane.getSelectedIndex();
                    if (selected != -1) {
                        if (currentRectangle != null) {
                            if (animator.isRunning()) {
                                animator.stop();
                            }
                            animator.removeTarget(target);
                            target = new PropertySetter(MaterialTabbedUI.this, "currentRectangle", currentRectangle, getTabBounds(selected, calcRect));
                            animator.addTarget(target);
                            animator.start();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected Insets getTabInsets(int i, int i1) {
            if(orientation == 1 || orientation == 3) {
                return new Insets(10, 20, 10, 20);
            } else if(orientation == 2 || orientation == 4) {
                return new Insets(7, 10, 7, 10);
            } else {
                return new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintTabBorder(Graphics grphcs, int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean isSelected) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) grphcs.create();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setColor(new Color(3, 155, 216));
            if (currentRectangle == null || !animator.isRunning()) {
                if (isSelected) {
                    currentRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
                }
            }
            if (currentRectangle != null) {
                if (tabPlacement == TOP) {
                    g2.fillRect(currentRectangle.x, currentRectangle.y + currentRectangle.height - 3, currentRectangle.width, 3);
                } else if (tabPlacement == BOTTOM) {
                    g2.fillRect(currentRectangle.x, currentRectangle.y, currentRectangle.width, 3);
                } else if (tabPlacement == LEFT) {
                    g2.fillRect(currentRectangle.x + currentRectangle.width - 3, currentRectangle.y, 3, currentRectangle.height);
                } else if (tabPlacement == RIGHT) {
                    g2.fillRect(currentRectangle.x, currentRectangle.y, 3, currentRectangle.height);
                }
            }
            g2.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintContentBorder(Graphics grphcs, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) grphcs.create();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setColor(new Color(200, 200, 200));
            Insets insets = getTabAreaInsets(tabPlacement);
            int width = tabPane.getWidth();
            int height = tabPane.getHeight();
            if (tabPlacement == TOP) {
                int tabHeight = calculateTabAreaHeight(tabPlacement, runCount, maxTabHeight);
                g2.drawLine(insets.left, tabHeight, width - insets.right - 1, tabHeight);
            } else if (tabPlacement == BOTTOM) {
                int tabHeight = height - calculateTabAreaHeight(tabPlacement, runCount, maxTabHeight);
                g2.drawLine(insets.left, tabHeight, width - insets.right - 1, tabHeight);
            } else if (tabPlacement == LEFT) {
                int tabWidth = calculateTabAreaWidth(tabPlacement, runCount, maxTabWidth);
                g2.drawLine(tabWidth, insets.top, tabWidth, height - insets.bottom - 1);
            } else if (tabPlacement == RIGHT) {
                int tabWidth = width - calculateTabAreaWidth(tabPlacement, runCount, maxTabWidth) - 1;
                g2.drawLine(tabWidth, insets.top, tabWidth, height - insets.bottom - 1);
            }
            g2.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintFocusIndicator(Graphics grphcs, int i, Rectangle[] rctngls, int i1, Rectangle rctngl, Rectangle rctngl1, boolean bln) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintTabBackground(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean isSelected) {
            if (tabPane.isOpaque()) {
                super.paintTabBackground(g, tabPlacement, tabIndex, x, y, w, h, isSelected);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you're not showing us, the `JFrame`, the `JFrame` layout manager, and the other `JPanels`, all have an effect on how the `JFrame` is arranged.  Create a simple [mre] with a `JFrame`, a `JTabbedPane`, and an inner `JTabbedPane` that we can compile and test in our IDEs that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: A non-pretty functional GUI is better than a pretty non-functional GUI.

Comment: *I'm also using a custom UI tabbed* - so first test with the default UI. I'm guessing it will work as expected. Then make one change at a time for your custom UI and retest. When it stops working you know what code you just changed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code wasn't runnable, I went ahead and created the following GUI.

[image: Nested tabs]

As you can see, there are outer tabs and inner tabs all shown inside of the bounds of the `JFrame`.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Here's the complete, runnable code, otherwise known as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NestedJTabbedPanes implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new NestedJTabbedPanes());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Nested JTabbedPanes");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createOuterTabbedPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JTabbedPane createOuterTabbedPane() {
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        JPanel panel = createBlankPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab #1", panel);
        JTabbedPane innerPane = createInnerTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab #2", innerPane);
        panel = createBlankPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab #3", panel);
        panel = createBlankPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab #4", panel);

        return tabbedPane;
    }

    private JTabbedPane createInnerTabbedPane() {
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        JPanel panel = createBlankPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab #1", panel);
        panel = createBlankPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab #2", panel);
        panel = createBlankPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab #3", panel);
        panel = createBlankPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab #4", panel);

        return tabbedPane;
    }

    private JPanel createBlankPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

        return panel;
    }

}
```